# Oracle SQL query not working in php but in SQL Developer

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have problems with this simple query:

```
UPDATE EWO_REFERENCE SET EWO_REF_HIDDEN=1 WHERE EWO_REF_ID=5430
```

The code above is printed in php.

If I execute this in Oracle SQL developer, it works fine.
If I execute this with the oci functions in php, i get the following error: "936 ORA-00936: missing expression".

The connection to the db is ok, because i can execute other queries in php without any problems.

I have no idea what causes this error, because the columns being updates have a simple number format.

Comment: As the update command itself seems right: I guess before asking you double-checked i.e. via `var_dump()` that you're really sending (and sending only!) what you think you're sending?

Comment: Of course I have checked it. var_dump() gives: string(62) "UPDATE EWO_REFERENCE SET EWO2=1 WHERE EWO_REF_ID=5690"

Comment: Try and do the same using bind variables (which you should be doing anyway) http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php also if you have a dev db remove the where clause and see if it works. The only possible errors are - TABLE/COLUMN doesn't exist, COLUMNS are being compared/set to an invalid datatype.